# gdb:How to print value at memory address in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

```
   0x08048c62 <+0>:     sub    $0x2c,%esp
   0x08048c65 <+3>:     lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c69 <+7>:     mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048c6d <+11>:    lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c71 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048c75 <+19>:    movl   $0x804a73d,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048c7d <+27>:    mov    0x30(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c81 <+31>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048c84 <+34>:    call   0x80488d0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
=> 0x08048c89 <+39>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
```

How do I print out what is at `$0x1` in the last instruction?
I tried all combinations

```
x/d 0x1
x/d $0x1
x/s $0x1
...
...
```

But I either get 
error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1, or Value can't be converted to integer(even when I try changing type to c,s,x,a)

Ultimately, I'm trying to find out the arguments passed to `scanf`, ie, "%d %d %c"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$1` there is an immediate value, it's just the number `1`. It's not an address. It's checking the return value of `sscanf`, that is the number of items processed. The converted values are of course placed in memory at the pointers that have been passed to `sscanf` as arguments.

In your example, the format string is at `0x804a73d`, you should be able to print that using `x/s 0x804a73d`.

The code is using `mov` to put items on the stack instead of `push` for efficiency reasons. You can see the arguments at the proper offsets on the stack. They start at `(%esp)` and each is 4 bytes:

1st argument (the string to read from):

```
   0x08048c7d <+27>:    mov    0x30(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c81 <+31>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
```

2nd argument (the format string):

```
   0x08048c75 <+19>:    movl   $0x804a73d,0x4(%esp)
```

3rd argument (1st output pointer):

```
   0x08048c6d <+11>:    lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c71 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
```

4th argument (2nd output pointer):

```
   0x08048c65 <+3>:     lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c69 <+7>:     mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
```

Comment: Well then my question is now: How do I know what is passed to scanf as arguments when I don't see any push instructions?

Comment: @filposs look for `mov`s to memory addresses such as `(%esp)`, `4(%esp)`, etc. This is similar to `push`, but without having to decrement `%esp` each time.

Comment: You seemed to have no problem at all knowing that it was there! Do you mind explaining to me an insightful way for determining this? of all the mov instructions, how would I know its this one? ( it was %d %d)

Comment: @Jester thank you! Is it always the case that the arguments from instruction mov are in descending order?

Comment: No, can be any order. You have to pay attention to the stack offsets.